# AWS S3 bucket folder files and sub folder give public permission using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to give the public permission to recursive to all the files of folder using AWS SDK.

for example

Bucket name: media
folder : images/2020-04

I want to make 2020-04 make public. such we give using

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 images/2020-04
```

Comment: So you want to make your files/object totally public, even if it means that literally anyone can delete them, upload what ever they want, download them?

Comment: Yes I want to make the entire folder public

Comment: Then have a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2). For action, using `"Action":["s3:*Object"],` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this policy to only grant access to `images/2020-04`

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement":[
  {
   "Sid":"S1",
   "Effect":"Allow",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": "s3:*",
   "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/images/2020-04/*"]
   }
  ]
}
```

You need to attach this policy to the bucket.

Note: replace **your-bucket-name** with your bucket's name.